# "Invalid entity model" error while exporting csv file for products

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

while **exporting a products csv file** from backend magento admin panel, it prompts me the following error when i click continue to generate the csv file.

**"Invalid Entity Model"**

I am using magento 1.6.2 CE.

** edited **

I am using magento default export/import services mean from admin system -> configuration -> export/import .....

plz ask me any question if it is still not clear .

Comment: More details are needed, like steps to reproduce, is it out of box or are there any 3rd party modules involved, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Open **abstract class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Adapter_Abstract**  and replace

```
$destination = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'importexport_');
```

to

```
$destination = tempnam(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/tmp/'  , 'importexport_');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Windows PC, it may be an issue with the permissions on the Temp folder.  I had to update the sercurity permissions through right clicking on `C:\Windows\Temp` and then select `Properties->Security->Edit...` and set the permissions to the group/user names appropriately.  I have given Full Control to all the users, to test it. I am on a Windows 7 PC.