# “Invalid entity model” error while exporting csv file for products in Magento 1.8

Tags: export, export-to-csv, product, magento-1.8

I need help !

I am trying to export products from admin panel but I am getting Error while exporting products and customers.

***"Invalid Entity Model"***

I have tried One solution from this link :

["Invalid entity model" error while exporting csv file for products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595957/invalid-entity-model-error-while-exporting-csv-file-for-products)

But it didn't work for me , so please can anybody know how to resolved this.

I am trying this by admin panel default import/export function .

Please help me ! I need to solved this error.

Thanks In advance !

Comment: I resolved My issue by using this solution : 

- Create Magento **root/var/tmp** folder

- Open abstract class 
/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php(63) 

and replace line number 60:

`$destination = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'importexport_');`

to

`$destination = tempnam(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/tmp/'  , 'importexport_');`

- Now reload and test

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Open abstract class `/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php(63)` and replace line number 60:

```
$destination = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'importexport_');
```

to

```
$destination = tempnam(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/**vars**/tmp/' , 'importexport_');
```

For some reason **var** was not working so i had to use **vars**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is can be a permission issue. Check the permission to the var/ folder